# I'm having problems using fetch() and can't fetch data

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, recaptcha, captcha

I'm trying to implement **Googles reCaptchaV3** on my website and I'm having problems when using the **fetch()** function.
So this is the code I got so far:

```
function sendData(name, email, captcha) {

    const info = JSON.stringify({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        captcha: captcha
    });

    fetch('/verifycontact', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'mode': 'cors'
        },
        body: info
    })
    .then(res => { 

        alert(JSON.stringify(res));

        res.json()})
    .then(data => {
        alert('msg: ' + data.msg + ', score:' + data.score);
    }) 
}
```

I tried alerting or console.log() the **info** object and it does console.log() before the first **then.()**, when I try to **console.log()** or alert the **res** object it just returns empty like this:

```
{}
```

Is something in the code that I'm missing? Maybe headers?
On my server I'm trying to **console.log(req.body)** but I get the same, it comes **empty**. My **body object arrives with this to my server:

```
{ success: false, 'error-codes': [ 'invalid-input-response' ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I needed to use the **bodyParser** to make the body to parse propertly.

I had to add this middleware to my router in express. This is the bodyParser config code:

```
router.use(bodyParser.json({
    verify: (req, res, buf) => {
        req.rawBody = buf;
    }
}));
```

And this is the middleware that I had to put on my route:

```
bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' })
```